# HDFS (WebHDFS) PUT/CREATE FAILS - getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

When submitting a request with the Python `hdfs` library I receive the following failure.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hdfs_test.py", line 128, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "hdfs_test.py", line 108, in main
    hdfs_stream.write(raw_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\util.py", line 104, in __exit__
    raise self._err # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\util.py", line 76, in consumer
    self._consumer(data)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 469, in consumer
    data=(c.encode(encoding) for c in _data) if encoding else _data,
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 214, in _request
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    low_conn.endheaders()
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\133041\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0D9A51F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test a **WebHDFS** `CREATE` command manually you'll see that it redirects to a `datanode`.

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test.txt?user.name=hadoop&op=CREATE"
```

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 17:16:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 17:16:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 17:16:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 17:16:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=hadoop&p=hadoop&t=simple&e=1563419760195&s=P2msnW447qKKXqfKcsEaTWSXnI0="; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 18-Jul-2019 03:16:00 GMT; HttpOnly
Location: http://datanode:50075/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=hadoop&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:8020&overwrite=false
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

The response from WebHDFS is trying to redirect you to the Hadoop **datanode**

Note the **Location: http://5fbeb0287619:50075** in the response.

This is WRONG!, this is the ID of my docker container because no host-name is set.

1. Make sure the datanode is accessible
2. Make sure the hostname is correct and can be resolved from the namenode and from where you're executing the script.

In my case I was using **Docker** so I needed to explicitly set my `hostname` inside my `docker-compose.yml` script. Once I did this everything worked.